# Highlighting nested occurences in C

Tags: c, string

I have a task like this:

> If you are printing the lines to standard output, print all occurrences of the found text in the lines in red. Be careful to correctly render “nested occurrences”, e.g. if the line contains aaax, and the search text is aa, the line should be output as follows:
>
> <red>aaa</red>x

I have the following code which finds the occurrence and highlights it, but it doesn't do it for subsequent finds.

```c
const char *RED_TEXT = "\x1b[41;1m";
const char *RESET_TEXT = "\x1b[0m";

for (int i = 0; newLine[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (newLine[i] == searchText[0])
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (newLine[i + j] == searchText[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        if (searchText[j] == '\0')
        {
            printf("%s", RED_TEXT);
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                printf("%c", line[i + k]);
            }
            printf("%s", RESET_TEXT);
            i += j - 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", line[i]);
    }
}
```

In the example, `newLine` is the text to search in: `aaaX`
`searchText` is `"aa"`

It finds the first two, but when it gets to the third, it only checks the `a` in front, which in that example is `X`.

Current output: `<red>aa</red>aX`
Expected output: `<red>aaa</red>X`

Comment: Have you tried using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens?

Comment: By the way, for the input `aaaX` there are two sequences of `aa`, do you want both to be "highlighted"? Because if you search for `aa` then perhaps your current code "higlight" the first pair and then skip over it. Leaving only `aX` which of course doesn't match.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes and that's the whole problem. It skips over them, but if it doesn't, it duplicates itself too.

Comment: Once you have an initial match, you should output the "highlight". Then skip over `newLine[i]` and *only* that character, and try the match again. Do that in a loop, and only output the "highlight" end when there's no more  matches. Separate it all into 
multiple functions to make it easier. For example `while (match(&newLine[i], searchText)) { ++i; }`

Comment: I believe related: [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “By the way, for the input aaaX there are two sequences of aa, do you want both to be "highlighted"?”: That is the whole point of the question. It is in the title. In is stated in the quote in the first paragraph to be careful about this. It is shown in the quoted example. It is shown in the OP’s current output and expected output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:  And that brings us to this: “Have you tried using a debugger…”: A debugger is useful for finding errors in code—code that was written incorrectly. Here OP needs a new algorithm to find overlapping matches. Debuggers are not good for finding errors in algorithms.

Comment: (By the way, the problem author should correct the use of “nested”. “aaa” does not contain nested matches, as neither is within the other. It contains overlapping matches.)

Comment: PSA: Instead of `printf("%s", x)` you can just do `puts(s)`.

Comment: @tadman `puts(s)` is equivalent to `printf("%s\n", s)`. Need to use `fputs()` to leave off the trailing newline.

Comment: First, use an algorithm that locates all sequences to highlight. This can be e.g. _Aho-Corasick_, which is linear, or an ugly and (worse than) quadratic hack, such as taking each pattern and trying to find matches starting from each character of each line. Second, when you find a match, take note of it, using e.g. a bitmap or, for convenience, a “bytemap”. Eventually the bitmap will contain a “sum” of all (possibly overlapping) matches. Third, iterate through the bitmap and output `RED_TEXT` for each change from `0` to `1` and `RESET_TEXT` for each change from `1` to `0` and merge it in.